# precedence order for annotations in aspectj

Tags: java, exception, annotations, aspectj

I have two different annotation which uses AspectJ Compile time weaving, say 
1) for retrying -- if a particular exception is thrown the method will retry itself 
2) translating exception -- i.e if particular exception is thrown will translate that source exception to target exception as specified

how can i define the order in which these two annotation will work. Both annotation are implemented using aspectj and use @around advice.

How can i achieve this type of functionality
`

```
Case 1
    @retry(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @translate(source = IllegalArgumentException , target = IllegalStateException)
    void method() {
        //if it throws IllegalArgument exception 
        //method should retry and translate it to IllegalState after it
    }
```

```
case2
    @translate(source = IllegalArgumentException , target = IllegalStateException)
    @retry(IllegalStateException.class)
    void method() {
        //methodthrows IllegalArgument exception which gets translated to IllegalState
        //method should retry for IllegalStateException after it
    }
```

`

can there be a way by which we can ensure the order of operation of annotation.

Right now when i run the code retry annotation runs first and then exception translation annotation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `declare precedence` in order to define your desired order of aspect precedence. Further information about this and default precedence can be found in the AspectJ Programming Guide, section [Language Semantics](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html#advice-precedence).

If the advice order should be dynamic, your best bet is to have one pointcut catch both annotations and decide about the order depending on the annotations' values which can be determined via reflection.